# Scan a dynamodb based on a list

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a String Set attribute i.e SS in a dynamodb table. I need to scan the database to check the value present in the any one list of the items.

Which comparison operator should I use for this scan?

example the db has items like this:

- name
- [email1, email2]
- phone

I need to search for a items containing a particular email say `email1` alone not giving the entire tuple.

Comment: Do you want do find items with ``email1`` as the single e-mail of the set or to find all items containing ``email1`` in the set and return only this value ?

Comment: I need to find items that has a given email present in a set of one its attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are looking for the `CONTAINS` operator of `Scan` operation. It basically is the equivalent of `in` in Python.

This said, if you need to perform this often, you probably should de-normalize your data to make it faster.

For example, you could build a second table like this:

- `hash_key`: name
- `range_key`: email

Of course, you would have to maintain this index yourself and query it manually.